# How to run CMD commands and hide it

Tags: vb.net

Hey i am programming in Visual Basic (VB.NET) and i am trying to run cmd commands without showing the cmd screen on the computer, I have the following code but i cant get it to hide it.. :(

Code:

```
Dim CMD As New Process
CMD.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
CMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
CMD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
CMD.Start()
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = CMD.StandardInput
Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = CMD.StandardOutput
SW.WriteLine("exit")
Process.Start("Cmd.exe", "/C systeminfo > C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Pictures\hello.txt")
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Comment: You need a four space indent to make a code block at this site.

Comment: You try read system info and do what with that info? save that info into file called `hello.txt` or just show somewhere into form?

Comment: There's no guarantee the "Pictures" folder is where you think it is. Lots of people move it to 2nd drives to save space on a small primary SSD, and lots of business environments redirect it to a corporate file server. Try `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures))` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ugly code aside, you can basically do it like this:

```
    Dim CMD As New Process
    CMD.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    CMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    CMD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    CMD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    CMD.Start()
    Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = CMD.StandardInput
    Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = CMD.StandardOutput
    SW.WriteLine("exit")

    Dim p2 As New Process
    p2.StartInfo.FileName = "Cmd.exe"
    p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C systeminfo > C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Pictures\hello.txt"
    p2.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    p2.Start()

    Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

Process.Start is a static method with a limited set of parameters for modifying its behavior.

So where you give the name of the .exe and the parameters via the static method

```
 Process.Start("Cmd.exe", "/C systeminfo > C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Pictures\hello.txt")
```

, is similar to:

```
    Dim p2 As New Process

    p2.StartInfo.FileName = "Cmd.exe"
    p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C systeminfo > C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Pictures\hello.txt",

    p2.Start()
```

But by doing it like that you have many more options available, including the option to set the WindowStyle to hidden:

```
p2.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
```

Comment: Thanks i just started to learn two days ago so that's why its ugly xD

Comment: I think you could suggest to use:  `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)` which will also consider, among other things, the current user Language.